# AAG expansion between datacenters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, disaster-recovery

We have a 2 node AAG setup in the DC data center, and due to an application requirement, it requires a third node to be created at the DR site and the only option I have is at the Data center in San Jose. What I want to know is - is creating an asynchronous connection a feasible option with AAG's (not AAG+FCI) . The 3rd node will be in a different subnet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely add a 3rd node to a DR site and have it be an asynchronous replica. It'll be a multi-subnet configuration, so be sure you add the MultiSubnetFailover=True to the connection strings to get a successful connection, that is if the drivers you are using support it.

You may want to disable the 3rd node's quorum vote in your configuration. I'm assuming you already have quorum setup correctly with a fileshare witness or something else (if you don't, then get that fixed). You don't want a network glitch to take down the cluster if you also have an issue on one of the nodes at the primary site. Be sure you understand quorum and votes and what's needed to keep production up.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helps. I also found this msdn link with a white paper which actually cleared most of my doubts. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191711.aspx . I also want to know if there is an easy way of copying over both AD and sql logins to the DR node. Is rev login script a suitable option?